# 'Google Now' Voice Search in Android App

Tags: android, voice

I'm not even sure if this is the right thing to do any more with Google not supporting 'Google Now', but I can't seem to find any suitable alternative.

Using this https://antonioleiva.com/voice_search_google_now/#comment-8611 as a guide I am trying o implement a voice search in my App, but not having much luck.

I already have a search facility for users. What I have done so far:-

**GlobalApplication.java**

```
public static Queries getQueriesInstance(Context context) {
    if(q == null) {
        dbHelper = new DbHelper(context);
        q = new Queries(db, dbHelper);
    }
    return q;
}
```

Then in **MainActivity.java**

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
  Intent i;
  int id = item.getItemId();

  ...
  ...
  if(id == R.id.nav_search) {
    i = new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
  }
  ...
  ...

  DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
  drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
  return true;
}
```

And finally, before adding anything, my **SearchActivity.java** file

```
package com.projects.activities;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.application.GlobalApplication;
import com.config.Config;
import com.db.Queries;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.libraries.asynctask.MGAsyncTaskNoDialog;
import com.libraries.dataparser.DataParser;
import com.libraries.location.MGLocationManagerUtils;
import com.libraries.utilities.MGUtilities;
import com.models.DataResponse;
import com.models.Deal;
import com.models.DealCategory;
import com.models.Status;
import com.projects.adapp.R;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
GlobalApplication.OnLocationListener{

private AsyncTaskNoDialog task;
SeekBar seekBarRadius;
SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefresh;
Queries q;
Button btnSearch;
ArrayList<DealCategory> selectedCategories;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_swipe_search);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    setTitle(R.string.search);

    swipeRefresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh);
    swipeRefresh.setClickable(false);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        swipeRefresh.setProgressViewOffset(false, 0,100);
    }

    swipeRefresh.setColorSchemeResources(
            android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
            android.R.color.holo_green_light,
            android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
            android.R.color.holo_red_light);

    showRefresh(false);
    q = GlobalApplication.getQueriesInstance(this);



    seekBarRadius = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarRadius);
    seekBarRadius.setMax(Config.SEARCH_RADIUS_MAX_VALUE);
    seekBarRadius.setProgress(Config.SEARCH_RADIUS_DEFAULT_VALUE);
    seekBarRadius.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) { }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) { }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            updateRadius(progress);
        }
    });
    updateRadius(seekBarRadius.getProgress());

    selectedCategories = new ArrayList<DealCategory>();

    btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
    btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            search();
        }
    });

    FrameLayout frameCategory = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameCategory);
    frameCategory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, CategorySearchActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, Config.RESULT_CODE_CATEGORY);
        }
    });

    seekBarRadius.setEnabled(false);
    btnSearch.setEnabled(false);
    if(!MGUtilities.isLocationEnabled(this) && GlobalApplication.currentLocation == null) {
        MGLocationManagerUtils utils = new MGLocationManagerUtils();
        utils.setOnAlertListener(new MGLocationManagerUtils.OnAlertListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPositiveTapped() {
                startActivityForResult(
                        new Intent(
                                Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS),
                        Config.PERMISSION_REQUEST_LOCATION_SETTINGS);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNegativeTapped() {
                Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, R.string.location_error_not_turned_on_search, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        utils.showAlertView(
                this,
                R.string.location_error,
                R.string.gps_not_on,
                R.string.go_to_settings,
                R.string.cancel);
    }
    else {
        refetch();
    }

    GlobalApplication app = (GlobalApplication)getApplication();
    app.sendScreenView(Config.kGAIScreenNameSearch);
}

public void refetch() {
    GlobalApplication app = (GlobalApplication) getApplication();
    app.setOnLocationListener(this, this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location prevLoc, Location currentLoc) {
    GlobalApplication app = (GlobalApplication) getApplication();
    app.setOnLocationListener(null, this);
    seekBarRadius.setEnabled(true);
    btnSearch.setEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public void onLocationRequestDenied() {
    MGUtilities.showAlertView(this, R.string.permission_error, R.string.permission_error_details_location);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == Config.RESULT_CODE_CATEGORY && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        selectedCategories = (ArrayList<DealCategory>) data.getSerializableExtra("categories");
        if(selectedCategories != null && selectedCategories.size() > 0) {
            TextView tvCategory = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCategory);
            String cats = "";
            for(int x = 0; x < selectedCategories.size(); x++) {
                DealCategory cat = selectedCategories.get(x);
                cats += cat.getCategory();

                if(x < selectedCategories.size() - 1)
                    cats += ", ";

            }

            if(!cats.isEmpty()) {
                tvCategory.setText(cats);
            }
            else {
                tvCategory.setText(R.string.all_categories);
            }
        }
    }
    if (requestCode == Config.PERMISSION_REQUEST_LOCATION_SETTINGS) {
        if(MGUtilities.isLocationEnabled(this))
            refetch();
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.location_error_not_turned_on_search, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

public void updateRadius(int progress){
    String strSeekVal = String.format("%d %s",
            progress,
            MGUtilities.getStringFromResource(SearchActivity.this, R.string.km));

    TextView tvRadius = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRadius);
    tvRadius.setText(strSeekVal);
}

public void showRefresh(boolean show) {
    swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(show);
    swipeRefresh.setEnabled(show);
}

public void search() {
    showRefresh(true);
    beginParsing();
}

public ArrayList<Deal> searchLocal() {
    EditText txtSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtSearch);
    String filterSearch = Html.toHtml(new SpannableString(txtSearch.getText().toString()));
    String searchStr = MGUtilities.filterInvalidChars(filterSearch);

    int radius = seekBarRadius.getProgress();
    int countParams = 0;
    countParams += searchStr.length() > 0 ? 1 : 0;
    countParams += radius > 0 ? 1 : 0;
    countParams += selectedCategories != null && selectedCategories.size() > 0 ? 1 : 0;

    ArrayList<Deal> array = q.getDeals();
    ArrayList<Deal> results = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Deal event : array) {
        try {
            int qualifyCount = 0;
            if(searchStr.length() > 0) {
                boolean isFound = searchStr.contains(event.getTitle()) ||
                        searchStr.contains(event.getAddress()) ||
                        searchStr.contains(event.getDesc()) ||
                        event.getTitle().contains(searchStr) ||
                        event.getAddress().contains(searchStr) ||
                        event.getDesc().contains(searchStr);

                if(isFound)
                    qualifyCount += 1;
            }
            if(GlobalApplication.currentLocation != null) {
                Location loc1 = new Location("Loc1");
                loc1.setLatitude(event.getLat());
                loc1.setLongitude(event.getLon());

                Location loc2 = new Location("Loc2");
                loc2.setLatitude(GlobalApplication.currentLocation.getLatitude());
                loc2.setLongitude(GlobalApplication.currentLocation.getLongitude());

                double distance = loc1.distanceTo(loc2) * Config.METERS_TO_KM;
                event.setDistance(distance);
                if(distance <= radius)
                    qualifyCount += 1;
            }

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            DataResponse categories = mapper.readValue(event.getCategories(), DataResponse.class);
            if(categories != null && categories.getCategories() != null) {
                for(DealCategory cat : categories.getCategories()) {
                    boolean isFound = false;
                    for(DealCategory selectedCat : selectedCategories) {
                        if(selectedCat.getCategory_id() == cat.getCategory_id()) {
                            isFound = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(isFound) {
                        qualifyCount += 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(qualifyCount == countParams)
                results.add(event);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return results;
}

public void beginParsing() {
    if(task != null)
        task.cancel(true);

    task = new MGAsyncTaskNoDialog(this);
    task.setMGAsyncTaskListener(new MGAsyncTaskNoDialog.OnMGAsyncTaskListenerNoDialog() {

        DataResponse response;
        ArrayList<Deal> events;

        @Override
        public void onAsyncTaskProgressUpdate(MGAsyncTaskNoDialog asyncTask) { }

        @Override
        public void onAsyncTaskPreExecute(MGAsyncTaskNoDialog asyncTask) { }

        @Override
        public void onAsyncTaskPostExecute(MGAsyncTaskNoDialog asyncTask) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            updateData(response, events);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAsyncTaskDoInBackground(MGAsyncTaskNoDialog asyncTask) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(MGUtilities.hasConnection(SearchActivity.this)) {
                response = syncData();
            }
            else{
                events = searchLocal();
            }
        }
    });
    task.execute();
}

public DataResponse syncData() {
    String cats = "";
    for(int x = 0; x < selectedCategories.size(); x++) {
        DealCategory cat = selectedCategories.get(x);
        cats += String.valueOf(cat.getCategory_id());
        if (x < selectedCategories.size() - 1)
            cats += ",";
    }

    EditText txtSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtSearch);
    String filterSearch = Html.toHtml(new SpannableString(txtSearch.getText().toString()));
    String searchStr = MGUtilities.filterInvalidChars(filterSearch);

    double radius = seekBarRadius.getProgress() * Config.KM_TO_MILES;

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("keywords", searchStr ));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", String.valueOf(GlobalApplication.currentLocation.getLatitude()) ));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lon", String.valueOf(GlobalApplication.currentLocation.getLongitude()) ));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("category_ids", cats) );
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("radius", String.valueOf(radius)) );
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("api_key", Config.API_KEY ));
    GlobalApplication.params = params;
    DataResponse response = DataParser.getJSONFromUrlWithPostRequest(Config.SEARCH_DEALS_JSON_URL, params);
    return response;
}

public void updateData(DataResponse response, ArrayList<Deal> deals) {
    showRefresh(false);
    if(response != null) {
        Status status = response.getStatus();
        if(status.getStatus_code() == -1 && response.getDeals() != null ) {
            if(response.getDeals().size() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, R.string.no_results_found, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            Intent i = new Intent(this, SearchResultsActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("deals", response.getDeals());
            startActivity(i);
        }
        else {
            MGUtilities.showAlertView(this, R.string.network_error, status.getStatus_text());
        }
    }
    else if(deals != null && deals.size() > 0) {
        GlobalApplication.params = null;
        Intent i = new Intent(this, SearchResultsActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("deals", deals);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    else {
        MGUtilities.showAlertView(this, R.string.network_error, R.string.problems_encountered_while_syncing);
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart()  {
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        default:
            finish();
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
    // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()  {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(task != null)
        task.cancel(true);
}
}
```

Taken from the tutorial link above, I then added the following to my Manifest

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
  android:name="com.projects.activities.SearchActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I then added the following to my **SearchActivity.java** file

```
private static final String ACTION_VOICE_SEARCH = 
"com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION";

private void handleVoiceSearch(Intent intent) {
if (intent != null && ACTION_VOICE_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
    String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
    setSearchViewVisible(true);
    searchView.setQuery(query, true);
  }
}
```

The in various places and in slightly different ways, I have tried adding

```
handleVoiceSearch(getIntent());
```

to the SearchActivity.java file, but I don't seem to be having much luck. I am testing from an Alpha version uploaded to Play Store.

Is there anything obvious anyone can see I am missing?

Thanks